# Many buttons to a single view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, popup, segue

im developing an app that utilises many buttons( possibly 20 buttons) on one primary view controller that can are all able to activate a singular picker view within a pop up on a seperate view controller.  i don’t think the answer is lots and lots segues. Is there a better approach I should be considering?

I’m thinking - some kind of multiuse segue that can be activated by any of the buttons, but nonidea how this is done.

Appreciate any advice

Mike

Comment: Create one action method and connect all to it. In that method init seperate view controller with any one settings.

Answer (score 1):

Set up all buttons to same action such as:

```
@IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender:UIButton){
    // use button title string
    self.keyString = sender.titleLabel?.text as! String
    // or tag
    self.keyTag= sender.tag?

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TheSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Then you would want to set up the View Controller that you are going to navigate to based on the state of the sender.  So you would override the `prepare:forSegue` method as below.

```
override func prepare(for segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any?) {

    let destController = segue.destination as! Dest_Controller_Class

    // use tag or keyTitle to set controller attributes
    // before view is shown

    destController.keyTag = self.keyTag
    destController.keyString = self.keyString

}
```

Now once you've navigated to the `Dest_Controller_Class`, you will have the properties of the button pressed locally in the view controller and could update the view as you see fit:

```
class Dest_Controller_Class: UIViewController {
    var keyString: String?
    var keyTag: Int?
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        if (keyString != nil) {
            label.text = keyString;
            // or likewise use tag
        } else {
            label.text = "keyString not set"
        }
    }
}
```